# Internet url as Android ImageSpan source

Tags: android, image, android-2.3-gingerbread

is it possible to specify internet url for ImageSpan and get it shown with `TextView`? I've tried quite a few versions of

```
String mockContent = "<img src=\"http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png\">";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mockContent), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

but that results in the generic *not found image* (blueish black bordered square).

Do I have to download the image first, then replace all the urls and so on?
Knowing the new C# is capable of handling such resources, I hoped Android might meet my hopes here.

Using API version 10: 2.3.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the image source locally then it should work or else use,

```
Html.fromHtml(String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)
```

**Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string.**

Nice example I found on web,

```
String s = Html.fromHtml(htmlContent, new ImageGetter() { 
        @Override
     public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {                   

        // Code for getting image either by download or using static iamge

         Drawable d = null;
        try { 
                    InputStream src = imageFetch(source); 
                    d = Drawable.createFromStream(src, "src");
                    if(d != null){
                       d.setBounds(0,0,(d.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                       d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
              e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();   
   } 


    return d;
    } 


  },null);
```

For more info  [Html.fromHtml with ImageGetter](http://www.developercaster.com/2011/03/android-tip-htmlfromhtml-with.html).