# How to show ImageSpan in TextView from html text received from server?

Tags: android, image, textview

Here is my problem:

At first, I send a html-text to the server:

```
Uri img_uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackage/" + R.drawable.emotion_smile);
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(editor_activity, img_uri);
int insert_loc = mEditorBody.getSelectionStart();
span_builder.insert(insert_loc, "`a`");
span_builder.setSpan(imageSpan, insert_loc, insert_loc+3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mEditorBody.setText(span_builder);
mEditorBody.setSelection(insert_loc+1);  

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post_req = new HttpPost(SERVER);
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

text_body = mEditorBody.getText();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", Html.toHtml(text_body)));

try {
    post_req.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
    response = client.execute(post_req);
}
```

the html text i sent is:

```
<p dir="ltr">1234567123<img src="android.resource://com.mydev.mypackage/2130837510">1238912<img src="android.resource://com.mydev.mypackage/2130837510"></p>
```

And Then, I try to restore the message in a listview:

```
viewgroup.textview1.setText(Html.fromHtml(item_list.get(position)), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

However, what i can see is only a image square:
[image]

Comment: well, seems nobody can solve my problem. I have to take a little trick solution: Instead saving text as html, I save it as pure text and the emotion is replaced by some unusual characters, such as "\`a\`". After getting from server, I replace "\`a\`" with the ImageSpan again

Answer (score 1):

Two other questions cover this issue and should give you what you need:

[Is it possible to display inline images from html in an Android TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview)

[Internet url as Android ImageSpan source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867572/internet-url-as-android-imagespan-source)